# How to represent message with sub messages?

Tags: c++, data-structures, networks

I am trying to implement a message that contains sub messages. The format would look something like the following.

`Message: Field 1, field 2, ..., sub type, buffer`

Depending on the sub type there could be one of several ways to interpret the buffer. Some of the sub messages might look something like the following.

`Sub type 1: Field 1, field 2, ..., sub sub type`

`Sub sub type 1: Field 1, field 2, ..., data buffer`

What I'm not sure about is how to structure my code in order to best represent the structure that exists. The sub messages don't inherit from each other, so I don't want to use inheritance.

Each of the fields represented in the message could be anywhere from 1 to 31 bits in length. Ideally I would like to have a struct/class with all `unsigned int` data types to make it easy to interact with the data and let the serialize/deserialize methods handle packing and unpacking the data before/after sending/receiving the buffer on the network.

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about a `union` of structs (classes).

Comment: Did you look at how TCP/IP does it? It is done that way and is very successful because it is one of the easiest ways to do it. LAYERS.

Comment: This sounds like you're reinventing the wheel; have you seen [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) ?   It may solve many of your problems for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may structure your object classes using [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).  This means referring in your message object to another object that will hold the sub type.

```
struct Message { 
    unsigned message_type; 
    unsigned field1; 
    ...
    unsigned fieldn; 
    Message *sub_message;  // if there's a dedicated type for this
};
```

If any sub type could have sub sub types, which may have sub sub sub types, and so on,  then you should consider using a [composite design pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/composite-pattern.html).

If your payload contains mostly unsigned integers, then you could make your classes easier to use with an array or a vector of unsigned integer.  This can help to avoid redundant code: instead of copy-pasting a lot of code to replicate similar behavior but for each field (for example print it on the screen, or serialize it), you could use a loop instead.

```
struct Message { 
    unsigned message_type; 
    vector<unsigned> field; // with a vector, the number of field could be variable  
    Message *sub_message;  // if there's a dedicated type for this
};
```

You could then define somewhere some rules, like for example the number of fields to use for each specific subtype.